# How to populate a RadioButton List with 4 answer choices in random order for a Quiz?

Tags: c#, .net, random, sharepoint-2010, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to create a quiz widget based off of SharePoint list data (Questions and 4 answer choices). 
I am able to find a way to pull 10 random rows and read the questions and answers. 
However, what I cant seem to come up with is logic to populate the RadioButton list with the answer choices (for that specific row item) in a random order. 
Here is the code I have thus far: Please suggest possible strategies/code

```
 //Function to pull 10 random questions from the "QuestionsAndAnswers" list for the correspoding LessonPlan
    public void LoadQuestions()
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            //Accessing the list correspoding to the current LessonPLan subsute
            SPList oSPList = thisWeb.Lists["QuestionsAndAnswers"];
            //Using a query in case there is a need tofilter by LessonID
            SPQuery oSPQuery = new SPQuery();
            oSPQuery.RowLimit = 10;

            SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.GetItems(oSPQuery);

            Random rand = new Random();
            List <int> tempStore = new List<int>();
            List <int> tempStore2 = new List<int>();
            int tempValue = 0; 
            //int tempValue2 = 0;
            int icount = 0;
            int iMax = oSPListItemCollection.Count;
            //int icount2 = 0;
            //int iMax2 = oSPListItemCollection.Count;
            SPListItem  thisItem;
            Label thisQuestion;
            Label thisCorrectAnswer; 
            RadioButtonList thisAnswers; 

            while (icount < 10)
            {
                tempValue = rand.Next(1, iMax);
                if (tempStore.Exists(value => value == tempValue))
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    tempStore.Add(tempValue);
                    thisQuestion = (Label) UpdatePanelMaster.FindControl("Question" + icount.ToString());
                    thisItem = oSPListItemCollection[tempValue];
                    thisQuestion.Text= thisItem["Question"].ToString();
                    //Inside loop to handle random answer arrangements 

                    thisAnswers = (RadioButtonList) UpdatePanelMaster.FindControl("RadioButtonList" + icount.ToString());
                    //The following 4 lines of code populates the RadioButton List only in order on  every row item run
                    //How to randomize the order?
                    thisAnswers.Items.Add(thisItem["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
                    thisAnswers.Items.Add(thisItem["IncorrectAnswer1"].ToString();
                    thisAnswers.Items.Add(thisItem["IncorrectAnswer2"].ToString();
                    thisAnswers.Items.Add(thisItem["IncorrectAnswer3"].ToString();

                    thisCorrectAnswer = (Label) UpdatePanelMaster.FindControl("CorrectAnswer" + icount.ToString());
                    thisCorrectAnswer.Text= thisItem["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
                }
                    tempValue = 0;
                    icount++;
                }
            }
            //End random question handling

            catch (Exception ex)
           {
             throw ex;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LINQ:

```
// start with an array of the question key strings
new[] { "CorrectAnswer", "IncorrectAnswer1", "IncorrectAnswer2", "IncorrectAnswer3" }
   // for each key string s, select the relevant answer string
   .Select(s => thisItem[s].ToString())
   // sort by a random number (i. e. shuffle)
   .OrderBy(s => rand.Next())
   // convert to a List<T> (for the ForEach method)
   .ToList()
   // for each answer string s in the list, add s to thisAnswers.Items
   .ForEach(s => thisAnswers.Items.Add(s));
```